# Redmine 2.4.4 - Web application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, redmine

I am running Redmine version 2.4.4 on RHEL 6. It works well, but this morning when I checked it, an error did occur.

```
    Web application could not be started

    cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in `running_bundler'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `'
    Application root
    /opt/redmine/
    Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)
    production
    Ruby interpreter command
    /usr/local/bin/ruby
    User and groups
    uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
    Environment variables
    TERM = xterm
    PWD = /opt/redmine
    LANG = C
    SHLVL = 2
    _ = /usr/sbin/httpd
    PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXIokuQq
    USER = apache
    LOGNAME = apache
    SHELL = /sbin/nologin
    HOME = /var/www
    IN_PASSENGER = 1
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
    NODE_PATH = /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/node_lib
    RAILS_ENV = production
    RACK_ENV = production
    WSGI_ENV = production
    NODE_ENV = production
    PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
    RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT = /redmine
    RACK_BASE_URI = /redmine
    PASSENGER_BASE_URI = /redmine
    HTTPS = on
    SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1


    General Ruby interpreter information
    RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3
    RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
    RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
    RubyGems version = 1.8.23.2
    Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
    DESTDIR = 
    MAJOR = 1
    MINOR = 9
    TEENY = 1
    PATCHLEVEL = 547
    INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
    EXEEXT = 
    prefix = /usr/local
    ruby_install_name = ruby
    RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
    RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
    exec = exec
    ruby_pc = ruby-1.9.pc
    PACKAGE = ruby
    BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
    USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
    MANTYPE = doc
    NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
    vendorhdrdir = /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/vendor_ruby
    sitehdrdir = /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/site_ruby
    rubyhdrdir = /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1
    UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
    UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
    configure_args = 
    vendordir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
    sitedir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
    ruby_version = 1.9.1
    sitearch = x86_64-linux
    arch = x86_64-linux
    RI_BASE_NAME = ri
    ridir = /usr/local/share/ri
    rubylibprefix = /usr/local/lib/ruby
    MAKEFILES = Makefile
    PLATFORM_DIR = 
    THREAD_MODEL = pthread
    SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
    EXPORT_PREFIX = 
    COMMON_HEADERS = 
    COMMON_MACROS = 
    COMMON_LIBS = 
    MAINLIBS = 
    ENABLE_SHARED = no
    DLDLIBS =  -lc
    SOLIBS = 
    LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib 
    LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static
    LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static
    LIBRUBY = libruby-static.a
    LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so
    LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.1.9.1
    LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
    RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
    rubyw_install_name = 
    LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS = 
    LIBRUBY_LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    EXTDLDFLAGS = 
    warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    debugflags = -ggdb
    optflags = -O3
    cxxflags =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    cflags =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    cppflags = 
    NULLCMD = :
    INSTALLDOC = all
    CAPITARGET = capi
    RDOCTARGET = rdoc
    EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
    ARCHFILE = 
    LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
    EXTOUT = .ext
    PREP = miniruby
    TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
    setup = Setup
    EXTSTATIC = 
    STRIP = strip -S -x
    TRY_LINK = 
    LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-R%1$-s
    LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
    LINK_SO = 
    LIBEXT = a
    DLEXT2 = 
    DLEXT = so
    LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
    STATIC = 
    ARCH_FLAG = 
    DLDFLAGS = 
    ALLOCA = 
    codesign = 
    POSTLINK = :
    WERRORFLAG = -Werror
    CHDIR = cd -P
    RMALL = rm -fr
    RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
    RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
    CP = cp
    RM = rm -f
    PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
    DOXYGEN = doxygen
    DOT = 
    MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
    MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
    INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
    INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
    INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
    SET_MAKE = 
    LN_S = ln -s
    NM = nm
    DLLWRAP = 
    WINDRES = 
    OBJCOPY = :
    OBJDUMP = objdump
    ASFLAGS = 
    AS = as
    AR = ar
    RANLIB = ranlib
    try_header = 
    COUTFLAG = -o 
    OUTFLAG = -o 
    CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
    GNU_LD = yes
    GCC = yes
    EGREP = /bin/grep -E
    GREP = /bin/grep
    CPP = gcc -E
    CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    CXX = g++
    OBJEXT = o
    CPPFLAGS =   
    LDFLAGS = -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
    CFLAGS =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    CC = gcc
    target_os = linux
    target_vendor = unknown
    target_cpu = x86_64
    target = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    host_os = linux-gnu
    host_vendor = unknown
    host_cpu = x86_64
    host = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
    RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
    build_os = linux-gnu
    build_vendor = unknown
    build_cpu = x86_64
    build = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2014-05-14
    RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 1.9.3
    BASERUBY = ruby
    target_alias = 
    host_alias = 
    build_alias = 
    LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
    ECHO_T = 
    ECHO_N = -n
    ECHO_C = 
    DEFS = 
    mandir = /usr/local/share/man
    localedir = /usr/local/share/locale
    libdir = /usr/local/lib
    psdir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby
    pdfdir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby
    dvidir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby
    htmldir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby
    infodir = /usr/local/share/info
    docdir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby
    oldincludedir = /usr/include
    includedir = /usr/local/include
    localstatedir = /usr/local/var
    sharedstatedir = /usr/local/com
    sysconfdir = /usr/local/etc
    datadir = /usr/local/share
    datarootdir = /usr/local/share
    libexecdir = /usr/local/libexec
    sbindir = /usr/local/sbin
    bindir = /usr/local/bin
    exec_prefix = /usr/local
    PACKAGE_URL = 
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
    PACKAGE_STRING = 
    PACKAGE_VERSION = 
    PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
    PACKAGE_NAME = 
    PATH_SEPARATOR = :
    SHELL = /bin/sh
    rubylibdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1
    archdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    sitelibdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
    sitearchdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    vendorlibdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
    vendorarchdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    topdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
    Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
    enumerator.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/buildout/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpdir.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/lib/phusion_passenger/analytics_logger.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
    Powered by Phusion Passenger, mod_rails / mod_rack for Apache and Nginx.
```

```
In file httpd.conf, i did not change anything from this:
<pre>
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
   </IfModule>
</pre>
```

I did not install RVM

$ gem evn

```
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
      - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-linux
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
         - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :benchmark => false
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - http://rubygems.org/
```

$gem list

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    actionmailer (3.2.17)
    actionpack (3.2.17)
    activemodel (3.2.17)
    activerecord (3.2.17)
    activeresource (3.2.17)
    activesupport (3.2.17)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3)
    builder (3.2.2, 3.0.0)
    bundler (1.6.5, 1.3.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    hashie (3.2.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hodel_3000_compliant_logger (0.1.1)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.3)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.6.1, 2.5.4)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1, 1.9.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.15)
    net-ldap (0.3.1)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
    omniauth-shibboleth (1.1.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
    rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
    rack-ssl (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
    railties (3.2.17)
    rake (10.3.2, 10.1.1, 0.8.7)
    rdoc (4.1.1, 3.12.2)
    rdoc-data (4.0.1)
    shibboleth_auth (0.3.3)
    sprockets (2.12.1, 2.2.2)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (2.0.1, 1.4.1)
    treetop (1.5.3, 1.4.15)
    tzinfo (1.2.1, 0.3.39)
    warden (1.2.3)
```

```
$ ruby -v
<pre>
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
</pre>

<pre>
    $ which bundler
    /usr/bin/bundler
    $ which ruby
    /usr/bin/ruby
    $ which gem
    /usr/bin/gem
```

I could not re-install Redmine because other users are using it.

Please give any idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths indicate different versions of Ruby in use.

- When you run `ruby -v` from the command line, it's showing 1.8.7
- Your `PassengerRoot` indicates 2.0.0 in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.38` (the directory under `gems` indicates the Ruby version the gem is built for)
- The error message at the top indicates `RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3`

Your best course of action is probably to uninstall the unneeded Ruby versions, then reinstall Passenger and Redmine.

Comment: hello Tim, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am not so good in Ruby, so I don't know how to uninstall Ruby 1.9.3 which I installed from source (and I can't reinstall Passenger & Redmine on system for many reasons). Hence, my solution is installing required gems for Ruby 1.9.3. I accept your answer because you gave me main point of problem: there are 2 versions of Ruby on my system. Thank you very much and best regards! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your passenger use other ruby version then in terminal. So, as i see, passenger use /usr/local/bin/ruby.

Try to install bundler in this ruby `/usr/local/bin/gem install bundler`.

And then i think you must run `/usr/local/bin/bundle install` from redmine root path

Comment: hello vladdruzh, yeah you're right. The root users see Ruby v1.8.7 and normal users use Ruby 1.9.3. I solved my problem in a similar way as yours. But I think your solution is correct! :) Thank you very much and best regards!
Note: "Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine."